# Adding Animation to the re-ordering elements of a div

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-animations

I was trying to implement a simple menu that I saw in the browser.

[image: Feature Demo]

I was able to implement the drag-and-drop feature using the draggable="true" property and also using some logic surrounding the drag-events, I was able to append the currently dragging element **before** or **after** the "dragged Over" ( the element over which we are currently dragging the element ).

```js
const dragables = document.querySelectorAll('.dragable');
const container = document.querySelector('.main-container');
const map = new Map();

const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((entries) => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const box = entry.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const oldCords = map.get(entry.target.textContent);

    const offsetX = oldCords.left - box.left;
    const offsetY = oldCords.top - oldCords.top;

    // console.log(offsetX, offsetY);
    if (offsetX !== 0) {
      // this means the element moved
      // do some animation.
    }

    // set new values.
    map.set(entry.target.textContent, {
      initiate: oldCords.initiate,
      top: box.top,
      left: box.left,
    });
  }
});

dragables.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('drag', hideDragable);

  element.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    element.classList.add('dragging');
    // Add event listener to all other classes.
    getDragOverNeighbours(element);
  });

  element.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
    // Remove the event listerners from all other classes.
    removeDragOverNeighbours(element);
    element.classList.remove('dragging');
    element.classList.remove('hide');
    mutationObserver.disconnect();
  });
});

let initiate;

function getDragOverNeighbours(dragable) {
  const dragableElements = [
    ...container.querySelectorAll('.dragable:not(.dragging)'),
  ];
  dragableElements.forEach((cur) => {
    //0. Assign Observer.
    mutationObserver.observe(cur, {
      attributes: true,
    });

    //1. Assign a new initiate Function.
    initiate = (e) => {
      findPositon(cur, dragable, e);
    };

    //2. Get the left and top
    const box = cur.getBoundingClientRect();
    const left = box.left;
    const top = box.top;

    // 3. store all in the Map object.
    map.set(cur.textContent, {
      initiate,
      left,
      top,
    });

    // 4. Add event Listener.
    cur.addEventListener('dragover', initiate);
  });
}

function removeDragOverNeighbours() {
  const dragableElements = [
    ...container.querySelectorAll('.dragable:not(.dragging)'),
  ];

  dragableElements.forEach((cur) => {
    // 1. Remove observer
    const {
      initiate
    } = map.get(cur.textContent);
    cur.removeEventListener('dragover', initiate);
  });
}

function findPositon(element, dragable, e) {
  // calculate the postion of the mouse on the dragable
  const box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const offset = e.clientX - box.left - box.width / 2;
  if (offset < 0) {
    element.classList.toggle('moved');
    element.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', dragable);
  } else {
    element.classList.toggle('moved');
    element.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', dragable);
  }
}

function hideDragable(element) {
  element.target.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Draggable Items</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">1</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">2</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">3</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">4</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">5</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">6</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">7</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">8</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">9</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">10</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">11</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">12</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">13</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">14</div>
    <div class="dragable" draggable="true">15</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Look at the Demo here. https://codepen.io/Noya52/pen/KKrqYQB

But I am not able to add smooth transitions for the re-ordering of list elements. When I drag and change the position of an element all the other elements re-order almost instantly. I tried applying transitions to elements, but the transition occur only after the re-ordering of the list items has been done.

Can anyone suggest what should I do to get the desired effect ? ( see Feature Demo ).